# what is the CValidationInterface class in the Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

There is class [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/validationinterface.h#L76) in the Bitcoin Core, I tried to learn about it and what is its job but couldn't figure out anything useful.

```
/**
 * Implement this to subscribe to events generated in validation
 *
 * Each CValidationInterface() subscriber will receive event callbacks
 * in the order in which the events were generated by validation.
 * Furthermore, each ValidationInterface() subscriber may assume that
 * callbacks effectively run in a single thread with single-threaded
 * memory consistency. That is, for a given ValidationInterface()
 * instantiation, each callback will complete before the next one is
 * invoked. This means, for example when a block is connected that the
 * UpdatedBlockTip() callback may depend on an operation performed in
 * the BlockConnected() callback without worrying about explicit
 * synchronization. No ordering should be assumed across
 * ValidationInterface() subscribers.
 */
class CValidationInterface {
```

This class [was inherited](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/net_processing.h#L40) by the abstract base class `PeerManager`:

```
class PeerManager : public CValidationInterface, public NetEventsInterface
```

What are subscribers of the `CValidationInterface`? I read the comments but that wasn't much helpful for me.